# Missing Build.json file in Cordova App

Tags: ios, json, visual-studio, cordova, xcode8

I am trying to run my Ionic Cordova Mobile App on an iPhone from Visual Studio using remotebuild remote device on a Mac.

The issue I am facing is that my Visual Studio project is missing a build.json file which I have since created and entered the following:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXX"
    },

    "release": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXX",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer"
    }
  }
}
```

I keep receiving the following error: 
**Error:Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 -1**

I am using XCode 8 and Cordova CLI 6.2.0

Any advice as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue, XCode 9, Cordova CLI 6.1.1. I've put the build.json file in the project's root folder. I've also followed steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/ios-guide#xcode8, but it's still a no go.